# if statement isnt comparing numerical values in my string c++

Tags: c++, string, validation, for-loop, if-statement

Assignment is to have a user enter a password that has certain requirements like length, and upper case/lowercase letters, and numbers. When I try and run the for loop that adds the amount of numbers in the string, it appears to skip the if statement.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cstring>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
  const int LENGTH = 13;
  char str[LENGTH];
  int size = 0, k = 0, j = 0, r = 0;

 cout << "Enter a password." << endl;
 cout << "Must meet these requirements:" <<  endl;
 cout << "At least 10 and at most 12 characters." << endl;
 cout << "Any characters entered after 12 will be ignored." << endl;
 cout << "At least 2 lower case, and 2 upper case letters." << endl;
 cout << "At least 3, but no more than 5 numerical digits." << endl;
 cout << "No white spaces." << endl;

 cin.getline(str, LENGTH);

//Validating numerical values.
for (int z=0; z < 12; z++)
{
 if (str[z] >=0 && str[z] <=10)
{
 r++;
 }
}

 if (r<3 || r>5)
 {
cout << "Must have at least 3 but no more than 5 numerical digits."<<endl;
 exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: `str[z] >=0 && str[z] <=10` => `str[z] >='0' && str[z] <='10'`. Characters and numbers are not the same thing. You need to check the ASCII values

Comment: @Mitchel0022 -- `'10'` is a valid character constant, but it's not useful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code you are checking for the ASCII Values between 0 and 10 but you want to check for the characters between '0' and '9'.
You can check the values of these characters on an ASCII Table and use these values:

```
if(str[z] >= 60 && str[z] <= 71)
```

or use the characters:

```
if(str[z] >='0' && str[z] <='9')
```

Comment: Don't use the ASCII values. Use `'0'` and `'9'`.